why the mysql 8 database auto generate a long running transaction
Today when I run an update command run spring boot application, the MySQL 8 generate a long running transaction and block the next update command. This is the output when I check the transaction:
select * FROM information_schema.INNODB_TRX 

and this is the output:
trx_id,trx_state,trx_started,trx_requested_lock_id,trx_wait_started,trx_weight,trx_mysql_thread_id,trx_query,trx_operation_state,trx_tables_in_use,trx_tables_locked,trx_lock_structs,trx_lock_memory_bytes,trx_rows_locked,trx_rows_modified,trx_concurrency_tickets,trx_isolation_level,trx_unique_checks,trx_foreign_key_checks,trx_last_foreign_key_error,trx_adaptive_hash_latched,trx_adaptive_hash_timeout,trx_is_read_only,trx_autocommit_non_locking,trx_schedule_weight
"14688701","RUNNING","2024-07-07 16:55:53",null,null,"21","3894",null,null,"0","6","13","1128","13","8","0","READ COMMITTED","1","1",null,"0","0","0","0",null

there is no sql query content in information_schema.INNODB_TRX's result, how to find out the where is the problem? The application update some record then add a new batch of record. seems the delete process is always processing. I have tried to tweak the MySQL connection timeout and autoreconnect to true. seems did not work. This is the application error log:
{conn-10049} discard com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet successfully received from the server was 10,000 milliseconds ago. The last packet sent successfully to the server was 10,002 milliseconds ago.
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:174)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.exceptions.SQLExceptionsMapping.translateException(SQLExceptionsMapping.java:64)
at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionImpl.java:2022)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidStatementConnection.setAutoCommit(DruidStatementConnection.java:89)
at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.connection_setAutoCommit(FilterChainImpl.java:715)
at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterAdapter.connection_setAutoCommit(FilterAdapter.java:964)
at com.alibaba.druid.filter.FilterChainImpl.connection_setAutoCommit(FilterChainImpl.java:710)
at com.alibaba.druid.proxy.jdbc.ConnectionProxyImpl.setAutoCommit(ConnectionProxyImpl.java:416)
at com.alibaba.druid.pool.DruidPooledConnection.setAutoCommit(DruidPooledConnection.java:732)
at org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager.doBegin(DataSourceTransactionManager.java:291)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.startTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:531)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.getTransaction(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:405)
at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:137)
at org.flowable.common.spring.SpringTransactionInterceptor.execute(SpringTransactionInterceptor.java:57)
at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.interceptor.LogInterceptor.execute(LogInterceptor.java:30)
at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:56)
at org.flowable.common.engine.impl.cfg.CommandExecutorImpl.execute(CommandExecutorImpl.java:51)
at org.flowable.job.service.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable.executeAcquireAndMoveCycle(AcquireTimerJobsRunnable.java:178)
at org.flowable.job.service.impl.asyncexecutor.AcquireTimerJobsRunnable.run(AcquireTimerJobsRunnable.java:119)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: com.mysql.cj.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

